# how to use "Microsoft tfs Shell Extension" in windows without VS installed

Tags: visual-studio, tfs, tfvc

i want to use tfs shell extension in windows 10 and i dont want install VS. download tfs shell extention from [here](https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=ms-vscs-vcw.TfsShellExtention). how to config that to show in windows context(right click) or other way without install VS. is it possible?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No, it's impossible.  As the official doc declared clearly:

> It works with Visual Studio 2017.
>
> **This release requires a computer with Visual Studio 2017** and all of
>   the [Visual Studio system requirements](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/visualstudio/productinfo/vs2017-system-requirements-vs).

You have to use Visual Studio with this *Microsoft Team Foundation Version Control Windows Shell Extension*.